# CSS dojo style doesn't get applied to button

Tags: css, grails, dojo, submit

I have built a form in Grails. I have used the `g:submitToRemote` button which dynamically creates a Html `<input>` tag. I want to apply a dojo style to it like to all other elements in my form like this `<g:submitToRemote dojoType="dijit.form.Button" />` but the style doen't get applied. Can you help me out to figure the problem?

```
<input onclick="createLoader(); dojoType="dijit.form.Button" try{//some Ajax calls};return false" type="button" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you need to check:

1. Are you sure the button is being parsed? Look at the HTML source and validate whether or not the HTML code of the button is still the same as the code you provided. When Dojo parses the HTML code it will usually change the HTML code to something more complex. If you don't have that complex code, your widget is not picked up by Dojo.
2. Did you import the correct CSS file? You need to make sure you imported the correct CSS file, for example `claro.css`.
3. Does any of the parent elements have the theme class name? If you use the claro theme (for example), you need to make sure you have the classname `claro` somewhere, usually in your `body`-tag.

---

**EDIT**:
More things to check:

Do you have `dijit/form/Button` in your `require()`? Assuming you're using Dojo 1.6 (because you're using the old `dojoType`) the code you need is:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
```

Is your button loaded asynchronous or not? If it is loaded async, your node will not be parsed when your page loads. This means you have to async it manually by wrapping your button in a `<div>` and manually parse that div, for example:

```
<div id="toParse">
    <input onclick="createLoader(); dojoType="dijit.form.Button" try{//some Ajax calls};return false" type="button" value="Search">
</div>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
dojo.parser.parse("toParse");
```

Comment: 1. My code is not parsed. None of Dojo code is present.
2. Claro.css is there. All other components are working.

Comment: Then you have to find the reason why your Dojo code is not compiled. Is `dijit/form/Button` in your `require()` block? I'm not really familiar with Grails but is the content loaded asynchronous?

Comment: This is present: dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');

Comment: And your HTML code is loaded synchronous (so it "exists" when your page is loaded)? Do you have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Also, what happens when you enter `dojo.parser.parse();` manually in your console? And what Dojo version are you using? Some versions require `dojoType="dijit/form/Button"` as attribute (but if you used this syntax in other component too, then it's unlikely).

Comment: When do you get that? When you use `dojo.parser.parse();`? And did anything change?